# How much difference does color make on the temperature of PVC decking?

Tags: deck, lumber

My wife and I have settled on Azek decking. I cannot find solid data anywhere on what recent PVC technology decking heats up to, and more specifically, the degree of difference between "light" and "dark" colors. My wife and I prefer the look of medium/dark colors, but the light colors should theoretically be cooler to walk on during hot days, and we have small children.

Does anyone know of a source that regularly gives reliable answers to this type of question? I've read both that "color doesn't make much of a difference for PVC" and that it makes a huge difference. Thanks.

Comment: Dark colors will absolutely absorb more sunlight and heat up faster than light colors. I personally don't know of any research/statistics, but you could do your own by buying one piece of each of the colors you're considering and just laying them out in the front yard on a sunny day. You can use a thermometer to test actual temps of them and your hand or bare foot to see if one is noticeably more or less comfortable to the touch than another or if any are acceptable.

Comment: I think it also depends on what you mean by light and dark colours.  The difference between light brown and dark brown will be much less than white and brown.

Comment: Try putting your hand on car roofs in a car park on a sunny day... you will soon see color makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend largely on where you live which is why any reliable information probably isn't available. I live in south Florida and have worked, drank, partied on every type and color of deck available and after a day in the sun, they are all too hot to walk for any length of time. Darker colors are worse than light colors, period. They heat up faster and stay hot longer.

Your decking will last at least 30 to 50 years with proper installation and maintenance so pick the color you like the most. Your small children with grow up fast and learn quickly to wear sandals or walk fast.